# add_action() function in wordpress not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am new in Wordpress and I am writing this code in my `functions.php` but it isn't working. This is my code:

```
<?php

function myFunction(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','myFunction');
```

This function must add my style.css in my page but is not working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add in header file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: Nice! it works. thankyou. By the way, can you please explain the purpose of this line?

Comment: bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ) function return theme style.css file url

Comment: <?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri same effect

Answer (score 2):

Please see all the parameters of [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Try below code :

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function myFunction() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myFunction' );
```

Answer (score 1):

**just** you should use the **`wp_head()`** in the `<head>` tag for applying styles

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: unreal, I searched for hours for this information. Not one of the ten tutorials I looked at for enqueuing scripts gives this crucial piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_theme_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_theme_setup' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_theme_setup() {

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourtheme_scripts' );

    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_scripts' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'main_style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array() );

    }
}
```

Here the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action gets called inside the `after_setup_theme` hook.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/